# How to create stored procedure to save history of specific column before update in postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

Basically, I just want to get the old value of a specific column before updating it and store it in another table. I want to accomplish this using a stored procedure in Postgres.

**transaction_table**

```
tid (primary)
status_id (integer)
```

**history_table**

```
hid (primary)
tid (integer)
old_value (integer)
new_value (integer)
date (timestamp)
```

Any changes in `status_id` will be stored in the `history_table`. Is this possible?

Comment: There are several solutions out there. See [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/) or [here](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/) or [here](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/auditing-data-changes-postgres)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical way to do that is to use a trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trans_hist() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   INSERT INTO history_table (tid, old_value, new_value, date)
   VALUES (NEW.tid, OLD.status_id, NEW.status_id, chrrent_timestamp);

   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER trans_hist AFTER UPDATE ON transaction_table
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trans_hist();
```